# index creation times out with ProcessClusterEventTimeoutException

Tags: elasticsearch

I suddenly cannot create an index (neither explicitly nor by indexing something into an index which does not exist). Other operations are fine (indexing, searching). The error I get in `security.log` is:

```
[2015-02-10 15:48:46,303][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.create] [eu4] [yoptest2] failed to create
org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.ProcessClusterEventTimeoutException: failed to process cluster event (create-index [yoptest2], cause [auto(index api)]) within 1m
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$2$1.run(InternalClusterService.java:263)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is a cluster of three machines (health green) and I get the same timeout no matter which node I hit.

What can be the cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got around the problem by rebooting all nodes. This is not a solution, I do not know the root cause of the problem but at least everything works again.

Comment: Hey you @WoJ you saved my day, heh!!

Comment: did you find the rootcause? currently having the same issue

Comment: I also did the same and it's worked, Anyone found root cause?

Answer (score -1):

It will gets solved by simply stopping the service and again starting the service.
For Windows you can start by running `elasticsearch.bat` file from `bin` folder.